# changing text color globally with new style

Tags: android, android-layout

EDIT:  My line in AndroidManifest was wrong.  It should have been

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

Now all the text color has changed.  Not the button color but I am on my way.  Thanks for the help.

---

This must be an easy answer but I keep getting errors.  I am, as far as I can tell, following the Android documentation [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) but it doesn't work.  I have read many stactoverflow threads on this issue and trying to follow what seemed like the best one.  The goal is to change the text color globally in an already complete project.

This is in res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="style_name" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I reference it in AndoridMinafest.xml

```
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/style_name" 
    >
```

What I am trying to do is keep the basic style of Theme.Black but change the text color.

What am I doing wrong?  The line android:theme="@android:style/style_name"  in AndroidManifest generates an error which then errors out every class.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be as easy as that. If you look at the builtin themes the text colour is defined in each type of component.

Comment: Have a look at this style.xml and how the text colours are defined for each style. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml . Sometimes it's inherited, sometimes its an attribute and sometimes it just hardcoded.

Comment: Perhaps I need to have the parent be TextAppearance.Large as all my text is of that style.  But then how to I then also have Theme.Black be the main theme?

Comment: If you look at how the Holo theme is defined there it should be a reasonable example to follow. The basically extend the default behaviour and define a new Holo specific version. e.g. <style name="TextAppearance.Holo.Large" parent="TextAppearance.Large"></style>

Comment: I guess I need some reference to an example of how I would tie it all into the app.  What do I put in AndroidManifest and what files I put where.  I am afraid I am just not getting it.

Comment: Thanks for the help @LionelPort    See my answer.  Just a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was close, just a typo but as I was unable to find an answer to this on the web and found lots of people asking I thought I would document exactly what ended up working.  This did not work for the cases where I had hard coded a color but I would not expect that to happen.  This did change all the default text colors.

AndroidManifest was modified like this:

```
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
     >
```

And the file res/values/styles.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffff00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this works.  All the text is yellow -- except the text defined as

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

And that is another story.  I will have to edit each instance to change that.